# Scope: Remove an element that was created in a for loop (Js)

Tags: javascript, loops, scope

A little background info :

input boxes with buttons next to them (buttons to remove each one) are created with a for loop. (The amount created depends on how many the user left on screen before the page reload).
Obviously the 'remove' buttons do not work, as they were created in a loop, due to scope issues.

Relavent code below:

```
for (var x = 0; x < currentTerms.length; x++){
        amt++;
    }

    //This loop creates the necessarry amount of inputs needed, given the amount of stored
    //search terms:
    for (var f = 1; f < amt; f++){
        var id = idVal++;
        count++;
        //Create a div to hold the new input box &
        //the new "remove" button:
        var divv = document.createElement("div");
        divv.setAttribute("id", "div"+count);
        divv.setAttribute("class", "divvv");
        inputContainer.appendChild(divv);

        //Create the new input field, set the type, class & id.
        var newField = document.createElement("input");
        newField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        newField.setAttribute('class', 'field');
        newField.setAttribute('id', "field"+id);
        divv.appendChild(newField);

        //The deleteCont div holds the remove button and it is 
        //added to the other div, now there is an input field
        //and another div inside the div:
        var deleteCont = document.createElement("div");
        var divId = "cont"+count;
        deleteCont.setAttribute("id", id);
        deleteCont.setAttribute("class", "remCont");
        divv.appendChild(deleteCont);

        //Finally, create the remove button itself and add it to the
        //container div that was created and place in the initial div:
        var remove = document.createElement("input");
        remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
        remove.setAttribute("value", "-");
        remove.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
        remove.setAttribute('id', "remove"+id);
        deleteCont.appendChild(remove);

        //When the user clicks the remove button with "-" value:
        remove.onclick = function () { 
            divv.parentNode.removeChild(divv);
            //Remove the error that may have been onscreen:
            document.getElementById("max").style.visibility="hidden";
            count--;
            toggleAddButton("show");
        };
    }
```

In the function that is called when the user clicks the remove button, you can see that it of course doesn't know which 'divv' element to remove.

To my understanding this can be resolved quite easily with something like .nameIndex ?
I just can't remember how it's done.

Any pointers would be a great help.

Comment: you're forgetting that every DOM element is part of the DOM tree, and has complete awareness of its parent and children elements. Plus, events like 'onclick' also have awareness of which element the event occured on. You don't have to keep track of "which" element an event occured on, because that's actually recorded in the event. From the event you can trivially look "up" and "down" and "sideways" in the tree for whatever you need.

Comment: Can you make the `onclick` method pass in itself as an argument? That makes the scope obvious (and explicit). For example: `button onclick="remove(this)"` will pass the `button` element itself into the `remove()` method

Comment: Interesting, if that's the case why doesn't the code above work? On the same page it works fine (without a for loop), that's what lead me to believe it was a scope issue

Comment: Solved: By passing the id of the div to be removed into the onclick function and referencing it that way

Comment: scratch that, still removes wrong item.